# Should I Shutdown Google Cloud Pub Sub Publisher After Each Publish In Java

Tags: java, playframework, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a backend application built in Java Play framework, and I started using **pub sub** to publish integration events when something happen in my service.

I have a singleton class that wraps the google **pub sub library**.

I have `placeOrder` command that creates an order and place it, after it I need to publish pub sub event `orderPlaced`

my question is about the following:

Should I shutdown the publisher after each time an event is published?
or it's possible to create the publisher once at the start of the server and still use it as this works with the singleton pattern that I am implementing.

Comment: Singleton pattern is fine. Do you have issues? latency or something else?

Comment: Can you address @guillaume's question to better help you? Or have you found an alternative that worked better on your use case?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have tried the singleton pattern and found it works fine without issues